# Generate Microsoft Word documents from plain text + style definition

Tags: text-editor, document-converter, plain-text, microsoft-word

I have to generate a Microsoft Word document (many, but all of them using the same template). I would like to generate it in the same way in which I generate PDF documents from LaTeX sources, i.e. using a WYSIWYM editor, macros, Git, etc. In fact, if could use a more powerful programming language, that would be better.

In particular I need:

1. Compile to Word files.
2. Use cross references (ideally with something like cleveref).
3. Easily add bibliography (ideally with BibTeX, but I could implement that myself).
4. Ideally also: procedurally define diagrams with something like Tikz/PGF (but I could embed Tikz/PGF, generate an image calling some external program and then use it).

I thought initially of [**XSL-FO**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223584(v=office.11).aspx), but it seems to be at a different level of abstraction when compared with LaTeX. A painful one. I may be missing something, but I wasn't able to find a way to reasonably write a document by using it [directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223525(v=office.11).aspx) or some related tools. As far as I could see, it seems to be closer to Postscript than to LaTeX (lots of explicit absolute positioning). Most tags in [WordML](http://www.lenzconsulting.com/wordml/) are just one letter tags, not very human-friendly, and then I am uncertain about how to generate the actual DOC or DOCX from that XML.

**Pandoc** (and similar tools) seems to be limited to a basic set of features (as the ones available for Markdown), so that it can cover a wide range of formats, but at the cost of missing many features in each of them. Basically the output is garbled.

Similarly for the case of **latex2rtf**. The output is missing so much of the input that it is rather pointless trying to use it.

An interesting case is **pdf2htmlEx**. It generates a nearly perfect HTML output from the PDF, but Word cannot really open that HTML file properly. This means that it may be possible to generate a Word file from a PDF using some similar tool, but judging by the output of pdf2htmlEx, editing that file may prove as a challenge.

So the questions are: Am I missing something? Do you know about any sane tool that satisfies the three (ideally four) requirements that I wrote? Which is the best tool workaround to generate DOC or DOCX from plain text?

Comment: I use to write such a generator (without cross references though) using LibreOffice. LibreOffice's OpenDocument format is pleasant to work with, style and content are properly separated. LibreOffice includes a command-line tool to convert documents to various formats, including Word format. It could be part of a solution.